# Ignoring characters when searching ArrayList with Edittext

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how I can ignore all special characters and numbers when searching through my ArrayList with an Edittext.

Here is an example:

One of the items in my ArrayList is called "00 - Bar 9", I want to make it so that when I type in "Ba" it displays in my ListView. With the code I have it does not display because I need to type in "00" to begin with.

I'm not sure what I need to do to be able to accomplish this?thanks

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            hasinputtext = true;

            temp = new ArrayList<String>();
            int textlength = search.getText().length();

            temp.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
                if (textlength <= songs.get(i).length()) {

                    if (search
                            .getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) songs.get(i).subSequence(0,
                                            textlength))) {
                        temp.add(songs.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }

            getListView().setAdapter(
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp));

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: instead of `.equalsIgnoreCase()` use `(String) songs.get(i).toLower().contains(search.toLower()))`

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
if (search.getText().toString() .equalsIgnoreCase((String) songs.get(i).subSequence(0,textlength))) {
                temp.add(songs.get(i));
            }
```

use

```
if ((String)songs.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(search.getText().toString().toLowerCase())){
    temp.add(songs.get(i));
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to do it. You are doing `subSequence` of the songs list when there is no need.

Comment: I think you've miss understood what I meant. Now it doesn't work at all. I'll edit it to show what I meant

Comment: I am getting "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean"

Comment: if ((String)songs.get(i).toLower().contains(search.getText().toString().toLower())

Comment: It looks like it's missing a bracket from the end of the statement, add one more so it reads `if ((String)songs.get(i).toLower().contains(search.getText().toString().toLower()))`

Comment: I still get the same error for some reason, also, apparently there is no mehod called "toLower()" it's meant to be "toLowerCase()"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72680/discussion-between-dreagen-and-jack).